# Converting Maven to Gradle with module exec

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I've done most of the work with `gradle init` in order to convert my maven project to gradle. However, my pom file specifies the following code - and I'm not sure how to reproduce it in gradle.

Core.pom

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>xml-code-gen</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.path.to.main.class</mainClass>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: It seems that qhat you need is to configure a task with type `JavaExec`.

Comment: task xmlCodegen(type: JavaExec) {
  main = 'com.path.to.main.class'
  classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
compileJava.dependsOn(xmlCodegen)

Comment: Have you solved the problem?

Comment: Yes, Thanks - Ben Manes answer helped determine how to state a dependency on a task, and what to use as the classpath.